# Regex - Replace Syntax - Backreferences

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to loop through all the lines of a file and for each line that contains a " I'm trying to replace the match with the line itself but with a " at the end too.

I'm using syntax like this from .NET/C#:

```
Regex re = new Regex("/\"/"); // without escaping would be /"/
re.Replace(" someAttr=\"some text here", "$0\"");
```

Comment: p.s., Your regular expression should contain only your regular expression. Don't add slashes as you would in perl or javascript.  If you're just trying to match a single `"` character, your regular expression would simply be `"`, not `/"/`.

Comment: @brun ur regex `"/\"/"` should be this-> `"\".*"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Regex re = new Regex("\".*");
re.Replace(" someAttr=\"some text here", "$&\"");
```

First, you need to lose the slashes surrounding your regex.

According to this [.NET regex reference page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html), `$&` is the reference to the entire match, not `$0`.

Also with your current method, you would just be replacing one double-quote with two consecutive double-quotes.  Since you want to add the new double-quote to the end of the line you need to make your regex match to the end of the line, which is what the `.*` does.

Example: http://ideone.com/K5A7D

Comment: Weird. I can't get the $& or $0 to work. It just shows up in the replacement. I'm testing it in Sell's Brother's Regex Designer. See next comment.

Comment: actually "$&" returns someAttr="&$"some text here

Comment: @brun - What I have above is what you would use in .NET/C#, if you are using a regex tool try using `\0` instead of `$&`.  It is also possible that your tool doesn't support referencing the entire match, in which case you could surround your regex in parentheses and reference the first capture group with `$1` or `\1`.

Comment: Figured it out. Broken programmer (me). I set the multiline mode. And corrected my expression in the C# not the Regex Designer tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
line="some text.d.sd..dsd.";    
Regex r=new Regex("\".*");
r.Replace(line,"$0\"");
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work as well:

```
string line = "This is a string";

Regex re = new Regex("[\"].*");
re.Replace(line,"$0\"");
```